# Looking for direction for a Custom Gesture like swipe to scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, ios-4.2

I'm trying to have a sort of gesture that will seamlessly switch between a group of images this part I have sorted. The part that is catching me up is the gesture to do so and how I might introduce acceleration.

Basically the user would swipe as normal and after the swipe is registered it would change the image displayed and the faster once swiped the faster the image would change ideally it would then keep that speed until the users finger was lifted leaving the possibility to just scroll repeatedly through the images.

Any direction someone could give me would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up it's working out nicely so far. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you would be using a UIScrollView for this, setting the scrollView.decelerationRate property would allow you to manipulate the deceleration rate/scroll speed. To calculate the "swipe speed", take a look here: [Detecting Special touch on the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541962/detecting-special-touch-on-the-iphone) for some pointers.